# trying to hide html div from code behind c#

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to hide Div from code behind c# but its not hiding.
Here is my c# code

html div

```
<div class="form-group col" runat="server" id="CorpCol" visible="false">
```

C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (!IsPostBack)
{
            bool shouldHideCorpCol = true;
            HtmlGenericControl corpColDiv = FindControlRecursive(this, "CorpCol") as HtmlGenericControl;
            if (corpColDiv != null)
            {
                // Set the visibility of the div based on your condition
                corpColDiv.Visible = !shouldHideCorpCol;
            }
}
```

But its not hiding the div CorpCol